# Windows docker image deployment in openshift

Tags: docker

I have created the docker image using .net core2.1 in my machine. then I pushed that image to my docker hub account. after that, I like to deploy that docker image in the azure open shift. I am using deploy image option in openshift. I got this issue.

**Failed to pull image "myaccountname/docker-repository@sha256:ebe91623041fa6ccc4244b038": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = image operating system "windows" cannot be used on this platform**

Comment: One of the misconceptions I had about Docker when I started out was that a container, since it included the OS, was independent of the underlying OS on the machine running the container. It isn't. You need a Windows host to run Windows containers. But since you're using .NET core, you might be able to base your container on Linux?

Comment: thank you for you response.i am using FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1709 AS base image.can't i deploy that image in openshift?

Comment: i can't use base container on linux

Comment: It sounds like your OpenShift nodes are Linux based. You might be able to spin up some Windows nodes. This might help understand the issue: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Networking-Blog/Managing-Windows-containers-with-Red-Hat-OpenShift-Container/ba-p/339821

Comment: thank you @HansKilian .i read the document.i am also has openshift version 3.11.is there any configuration for deployment docker image?if i want to deploy that windows image what will i do?colud you please give me any suggestions

Comment: I'm not that familiar with OpenShift, but it sounds like the nodes in your current cluster are Linux nodes. If you want to be able to deploy Windows containers, you need Windows nodes in the cluster. I don't know if it's possible to mix Linux and Windows nodes in a single cluster or if you need a separate cluster with Windows nodes.

Comment: @HansKilian thank you for your information.it helps me a lot .i will explore this